# Computer often freezes because of Webpack

Tags: 18.04, freeze, nodejs

My computer freezes about 3 to 10 times per work day (8 hours). When it freezes, I can move my mouse, but barely. It normally takes about 5 minutes for it to respond again, at which point it says that `vscode` is not responding.

I looked a bit more into this and it appears that node is the problem. I once was able to stop the webpack command while it was freezing and that made it stop. I also at some point had the System monitor opened and, while I couldn't see the status while it froze, I did notice that node was spiking right before it froze, every time.

I am running Ubuntu `18.04`, webpack version `4.41.2` and Node version `8.11.4`. I have had this for a year or so now, so I don't think it has anything to do with any version.

Any tips on what I can try?

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.7G        6.5G        390M        550M        835M        399M
Swap:          2.0G        2.0G         52K
```

`/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw`

`vm.swappiness = 60`

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h`.

Comment: @heynnema Added

Comment: **Your swap space is too small**. Are you using a swap partition, or a /swapfile? Show me `grep -i swap /etc/fstab` and `sudo sysctl vm.swappiness`. Do you know how to increase your swap?

Comment: @heynnemaI added the swap commands. I have no idea how to increase the swap

Comment: If you make an answer with how to increase my swap and what to increase it to, I'll set it as the answer (if it works of course)

Comment: status please...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your system is freezing because your **swap space is too small**. Not because of webpack or vscode, per se. You may also need to **increase your RAM size to 16G** (use two equal size RAM sticks).

We can see this with the `free -h` command...

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.7G        6.5G        390M        550M        835M        399M
Swap:          2.0G        2.0G         52K
```

Note that the 2.0G swap is completely used up.

We also note that the entry in `/etc/fstab` for swap is incorrect...

`sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab`

Change:

```
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw
```

to:

```
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw  0  0
```

To increase the size of your /swapfile, use the following procedure. **BE CAREFUL**, as incorrect use of the `dd` command could cause loss of data... a good backup would be useful...

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off the current /swapfile
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # delete the current /swapfile
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096 # lets try 4G first
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set the correct permissions
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # initialize the /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # enable the new /swapfile
```

Use the `free -h` command to verify 4G swap, and to monitor your swap and RAM usage.